# Read the latest dataset using sql or sas

Tags: sql, sas

I have datasets in the DYYMMDD format

```
 D160102
 D160128
 D160227
 D160328
 D160430
```

How can i read the latest dataset on a monthly basis. Lets say there are two datasets in january month (D160102, D160128), i only want to read the D160128 and not the other one. How ?? Any help ?

Comment: any reason why you dont save that as a date instead of text? Things would be much easier

Comment: thats how it is in the company

Comment: Whoever designed this database should be beaten severely.

Comment: @StanShaw I wish so :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is in the table as a string, you could use substring to extract only the month value

```
Select * from (
Select
    Field 
    ,SUBSTRING( Field, 3, 2 ) as 'Month'
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by SUBSTRING( Field, 3, 2 ) order by Field DESC) as 'frnk'
) a
Where a.frnk = 1
```

Comment: You need extract `YYMM` not just `MM`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about SAS, but this is for MySQL, the idea is group together all string with same month `DYYMM` and get the bigger one.

**[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a343/2)**

```
SELECT MAX(dday) 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(dday,2,4)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| MAX(dday) |
|-----------|
|   D160128 |
|   D160227 |
|   D160328 |
|   D160430 |
```

Comment: Thank you Juan Carlos, but its a table name that i have to pick the latest one and not the date field in the column, apologies if i misunderstood

Comment: I see. So SAS is like SQL server? Because there are functions to get the name of all the tables on a db. In that case just replace `Table1` for a subquery returning all dataset.

Comment: sas is similar to SQL, datasets are tables and libraries are schemas.

Comment: Sorry I can help you more, maybe this give you some ideas http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001397000.htm

Answer (score 0):

A SAS data step solution. Read in the date as yymmdd and then output back as yymm6 so that it sorts by date descending and take only the first per group.

```
data have;
input files $;
cards;
 D160102
 D160128
 D160227
 D160328
 D160430
 ;
run;

data want;
set have;
date=put(input(substr(files, 2), yymmdd.), yymmn6.);
run;

proc sort data=want nodupkey; 
by descending date; 
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

So finding the latest one is easy, as other's have demonstrated.  But to then use it in the rest of your program you will need to use some code generation technique.  Like a macro variable.

Assuming that your list represents SAS datasets then something like this could be use to combine them into a single dataset.

```
data have; input dsname $ ;
cards;
D160102
D160128
D160227
D160328
D160430
;;;;

proc sql noprint ;
  select dsname into :dslist separated by ' '
    from have
    group by substr(dsname,2,4)
    having dsname = max(dsname)
  ;
quit;

data want ;
  set &dslist ;
run;
```